# how to compare 2 files column of a linux file to be compared with second column of another file and get the difference

Tags: linux, awk

How to compare 2 files? I need to compare a column of a linux file with the second column of another file and get the difference.

Let's say I have the following files.

file 1:

```
a 3
b 6
c 8
d 7
g 5
p 16
```

file 2:

```
a 1
b 6
c 8
d 7
g 5
```

I need to compare column two of file 1 with column two of file 2 and get the difference.

Desired output file 1 - file 2 :

```
a 2
b 0
c 0
d 0
g 0
p 16
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner works for your example:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $1,a[$1]-$2;delete a[$1]}
       END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: I think you want to type `?` instead of `!!` right? which part do you have problem?

Comment: Hello kent ,

What should happen to records present only in file 2?

Comment: @Govins if the question is like "what should happen..." or "what would happen..." you can test on your own.